# Xcode static libraries - path oddities

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, linker, static-libraries

I have a simple program I'm writing using ProtocolBuffers (libprotobuf) and Boost's ASIO library. I've determined that I need to link in libprotobuf.a and libboost_system.a, both of which reside in /usr/local/lib on my system.

Following instructions found in several places, I've added both of these .a files to the "Link Binary With Libraries" list, under "Build Phases". Both are set as "Required".

When I build, this generates a linker error:

```
ld: library not found for -lprotobuf
```

If I add the following (as two separate lines) to "Build Settings" / "Other Linker Flags" then the problem goes away: "-L", "/usr/local/lib".

My question is whether this -L hack to set the library search path is really the right way to do it. I'm not sure why Xcode isn't picking up the location of these libraries considering I've added them to the "Build Phases" / "Link Binary With Libraries" list. I would have thought their presence in this list would be enough info for Xcode to work out how to locate them. Both the .a files are also now shown in my project's file "tree".

So is there a better way to do this than what appears to be abuse of the "Other Linker Flags" setting?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: `-L` stand for library search path, you can find it as an option in project setting.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of what -L means to the linker. Do you mean the "Library Search Paths" value under "Search Paths"? I just tried that and it does seem to work - is this the best way to specfify this, and if so why isn't simply adding the libraries to the "Link Binary With Libraries" list sufficient? Or is that list not meant to hold the entire path but simply the library names, deferring to the "Library Search Path" setting to actually locate the library files?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to yngum, it appears that the best answer determined so far is to use the "Library Search Paths" field. With that in mind, it appears that the "Link Binary With Libraries" list isn't a list of full paths, but a basic list of library names that are later located by the linker. In effect, the "Link Binary With Libraries" list is analogous to `-l` options, and "Library Search Paths" to `-L` options typically passed to `ld`.